# C# File lock in Windows Service

Tags: c#, file, windows-services, locking

I wrote one windows service to do the following.

1. Call Hand Punch machine's vendor .exe to generate a text file to get data from Hand Punch machine. Store in a temporary folder. The .exe called using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`
2. Attach and send email the file

   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("f@abc.com", "t@abc.com");

   string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(...);

   foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
   {
       Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
       mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
   }

   client.Send(mail);
3. Move the file from temporary folder to Sent folder

I could accomplish step 1 and 2, but when I try step 3 ( to move the file), the file is locked by my service ( but I am sure it is not writing anything to it).

How can I move the file?

Comment: can you paste code snippet about File Create?

Comment: It is vendor .exe file. I run the .exe using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(

Comment: if you do those steps **manually**, can the file be deleted finally?

Comment: Yes. I can. I think the lock comes while emailing the file.

Comment: what step is editing?

Comment: Please don't just down-vote, post comments instead.

Comment: OP: how are you sending the email, how are you attaching your file to it?

Comment: string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files\HpDataPoll\hppull", "*.TXT", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);                    
                }

Comment: see my edit in the main post

Comment: SmtpClient.Send is locking files. Hope if I use 'using', it will solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

SmtpClient.Send is locking files. When I used 'using', solved my issue.